# Style Library/Images folder problem

Tags: 2010

I have developed a portal couple of months back using SharePoint 2010. My images are in "Style Library/Images" folder. It was working fine and whatever images ive places from that image library on pages were appearing fine too and in that time ive replaced and added many images without any problem.

Today a user requested to update the ORG chart so ive uploaded a updated image in "Style Library/Images" folder..checked in..but when i went to the page there was "X" mark there...being a site collection admin i can see the pic but users have "X"..

Also when user copy pasted the link directly in browser like this.
http://portal.domain.com/Style%20Library/Images/CMGOpsOrganogram.jpg they get "ACCESS DENIED"

what is the problem now with images folder?

Comment: I have a similar problem with the corev4.css file; new user is getting access denied to this file.
Where would you grant access to "Style Library/Images" or the '-Styles' folder in my case.
I don't see any option in neither SP Designer nor SP.
I don't have server access.
Thanks,
Laura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can happen only if users do not have access to "Style Library/Images" folder, check permission for the folder "Style Library/Images" if users(target group) do not have "View"/Read permission then grant View permission, your issue should be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Check publishing Feature if it activated means then check out and check in the current page.

or else check user having read permissions to Images Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I have this "Restricted Reader" group ..ive checked the permission and "Authenticated Users" group was missing..added back and it worked :) ..don't know who removed it..neway thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

add Type="GhostableInLibrary" property in `<File Path=".."  Url=".." />`